# sprite not being removed with SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying clouds move up  and spawn but  I keep getting

'terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:  name:'(null)' texture:[ 'CLOUD' (746 x 497)] position:{198.66667175292969, 1227.987060546875} scale:{0.30, 0.30} size:{223.80000305175781, 149.10000610351562} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00'. '

I'm not sure what's going wrong any help would be much appreciated

```
 let cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CLOUD")
 let cloud2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CLOUD")

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
          self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
 setUp()
}

func setUp() {

    let block = SKAction.run ({
        self.spawnClouds()

        if (cloud1.position.y  > self.size.height) {

        cloud1.removeFromParent()
            cloud2.removeFromParent()
        }
    })

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 9)

    let action = SKAction.repeat(block, count: 10)
            let removes = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([block, wait, action, removes])

    self.run(sequence)
}

@objc func spawnClouds() {
    let gapHeight = self.frame.width / 9
    let movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.width / 2)
    let cloudOffset = CGFloat(movementAmount) - self.frame.width / 4

   // let cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CLOUD")

    cloud1.xScale = 0.3
    cloud1.yScale = 0.3
    cloud1.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(cloud2)
    cloud2.xScale = 0.3
    cloud2.yScale = 0.3
    cloud2.zPosition = 1

    cloud1.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.minX / 2 + gapHeight / 5 + cloudOffset , y: self.frame.minY  )
    cloud2.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.maxX / 2 + gapHeight / 5 + cloudOffset , y: self.frame.minY  )

    self.addChild(cloud1)

    var distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * cloud1.frame.width)
    let moveCloud = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx:0, dy:25 * self.frame.width), duration: TimeInterval(self.frame.height / 15 ))

    let newaction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let new = SKAction.sequence([moveCloud, newaction])

    cloud1.run(new)
    cloud2.run(new)
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if cloud2.position.y > size .height {

        cloud1.removeFromParent()
        cloud2.removeFromParent()
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: That's a very poor way of presenting code and asking an unpaid volunteer to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

cloud1 and cloud2 are properties i.e. visible everywhere. So when you do `addChild(cloud1)` and `addChild(cloud2)` these are not newly create sprites but are the same ones you've added before, hence the message 'Attempting to add an SKNode that already has a parent'

In a function that is designed to spawn nodes, you usually create a new SKNode to spawn each time, just like your line of code that is commented out:

```
// let cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CLOUD")
```

This will make sure that cloud1 is a new node each time.

You should also be doing this for cloud2.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, the first is action should be a sequence.

```
   // let action = SKAction.repeat( block, count: 10)
     let action = SKAction.repeat( SKAction.sequence( [block,wait]), count: 10)
```

second ,the timing should be perfect around 9s, i.e. `self.frame.height / 15`

```
   //let moveCloud = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx:0, dy:25 * self.frame.width), duration: TimeInterval(self.frame.height / 15 ))
```

so this could be :

```
  let moveCloud = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx:0, dy:2.5 * self.frame.width), duration: TimeInterval(self.frame.height / 150 ))
```